# Product View Html

Tags: magento-2.1, html, page, page-layouts

I'm having a problem with the position of some of the objects of my product page. For example the header of the description is not aligned with the menu on the left and I have a little too much white space in between the product.main and product.info block. I know this would be an easy change within a html file, however I am unable to locate it. Any help?

I want to align the grey block to Hvorfor

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide me some Screenshot?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my problem

Comment: if you have a live URL then share please

Comment: https://www.safegear.dk/brandsikring.html

Comment: I just saw the page and it looks better , could you tell little more , what problem still exists